# Flutter Background behind an Element when you press/press hold something like a button

Tags: flutter

I do not know how it is called but I want to remove what you see on the picture (the darker grey part). I want that the grey square outline disappears when I click on something.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iJUP.jpg
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj0ny.gif

Comment: could you add the picture?

Comment: The picture is not visible, could you edit your question and show it?

Comment: Now I see. Could you post your code? Only with that part of the witget is enough and I can provide an anwer.

Comment: I updated the feed probably it is now a little bit easier to understand. I am sorry it is my first time posting something here and I am also new to coding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general..it is the splash color..

For ex: if we consider RaisedButton
you can do something like this..

```
RaisedButton(
 spashColor: Colors.green, //your desired color
 child: Text("hello"),
)
```

You can do the same for FlatButton also..

If you don't want any color..then you can set it to "Colors.transparent"

Answer (score 0):

Given that you state the widget seen in the image is a BottomNavigationBar, you can set the background color via the backgroundColor attribute.

You can set this attribute to the desirer color or a transparency (which would reveal the underlying scaffold color instead)

However, if the widget in question turns out to be a shifting background navigation bar the background color of the inner item's will overwite that. In which case you would instead need to set the background color of the specific item.

Source : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar/backgroundColor.html